# How to update the columns values when they have no value

Tags: sql, null

For Example Table Test has the below schema with 4 records:

```
id H1   H2  H3  H4 H5
1  X    Y   Z   M   N
2       K   L   N   O
3  G        M       P
4  J    K       N

Ouput I want is :
id H1 H2    H3  H4 H5
1  X   Y    Z   M   N
2  K   L    N   O
3  G   M    P
4  J   K    N
```

I am trying to implement this using case statements. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate all columns without empty elements, split again, address array elements:

```
with data as(
select stack(4,
1  ,'X','Y','Z','M','N',
2  ,null,'K','L','N','O',
3  ,'G',null,'M',null,'P',
4  ,'J',null,'K',null,'N'
) as (id,ad1,ad2,ad3,ad4,ad5)
)

select id, a[0] as ad1, a[1] as ad2, a[2] as ad3, a[3] as ad4, a[4] as ad5
from
(
select id, split(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(concat_ws(',',nvl(ad1,''),nvl(ad2,''),nvl(ad3,''),nvl(ad4,''),nvl(ad5,'')),'^,+|,+$',''),',{2,}',','),',') a
from data
)s
```

Result:

```
id      ad1     ad2     ad3     ad4     ad5
1       X       Y       Z       M       N
2       K       L       N       O       NULL
3       G       M       P       NULL    NULL
4       J       K       N       NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.394 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Explanation:
First `regexp_replace` removes one or more leading and trailing commas `'^,+|,+$'`. 
Second `regexp_replace` replaces two or more commas `',{2,}'` with single one.
`split` creates array.